# Session data is always null in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an API where I want to store in the session the `User` object after the login. The `HttpContext.Session.SetString` method works well, but if I want to use the `GetString` method in another process as like in a `HttpGet` method, the passed string is always null or empty.

If I call this `GetString` method directly after the `SetString` method, then the value returned by the `GetString` method is not empty.

In my `Program.cs` I used this:

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
});
```

And I also used at the correct place the `app.UseSession()` method

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllers();
```

In my controller, the Login post method, and the other method, looks like this.

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> LoginUser(User user)
{
    var result = await _userService.LoginUser(user);

    if (result is null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Helytelen felhasználónév vagy jelszó");
    }

    // HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", result.username);
    // Console.WriteLine($"Username set to: {result.username}");

    var userJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result);
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("User", userJson);

    Console.WriteLine($"User set to: {userJson}");

    return Ok(result);
}

[HttpGet("welcome")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Welcome()
{
    // var username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");
    // Console.WriteLine($"Username set to: {username}");
    var userJson = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userJson))
    {
        return BadRequest("Nem vagy bejelentkezve");
    }
    /*else
    {
        return Ok(username);
    }*/

    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(userJson);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Firstly I tried to pass only the username, but it was a failure too.

Comment: That is because it is in another process, Session variables are not shared across processes...

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thanks for your answer.
I'm a bit confused now.., so what should I do instead of this ? I already tried JWT tokens, but the truth is, this Http.Sessions looked more easier, or is there any alternative mode, to store user's data after login ? I want to create only a simple web-app, where users are able to create events with using map (Like leaflet). ( This project is for my state-exam... it is not planned to run in live servers.

Comment: In my opinion, the JWT token is enough, you could store the claims like user name, Email or else inside that JWT token, then you could read the user data from this token instead of using the Http Session.

Comment: The configuration you show does work for me. I assume that _“in another process”_ meant “in another request but the same ASP.NET Core application” in which case this is exactly how sessions are supposed to work. I tried your snippets in a new ASP.NET Core application and it worked for me, so your problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: My welcome request does not give back any cookies in my browser... I think my problem could be somewhere there..

Comment: Please check the domain to make sure the session ID is stored inside the cookie